# dataweave expression to map json to flat file

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

Im new to mulesoft, trying to extract database to a flatfile via json in mulesoft. Please help in writing dataweave expression for converting json payload to flatfile.

[image: mule flow:]

and my flat file schema is:

[image: StudentDetailsSchema.ffd]

With the above I'm getting exception like:

[image]

Comment: It is better to include the actual code, text, etc in order to prevent a user from navigating away from the subject. It also helps with giving the user the ability to cut and paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's expecting a map not an array(map in dataweave returns an array) If you want to ouptut an array, you need to modify your FFD schema so that it know its an array, using:

```
  - { idRef: 'PersonalInfo', count: '>1' } 
  - { idRef: 'CourseDetails', count: '>1' }
```

That will fix your transform.

Comment: Great. Can you accept the answer using the tick/check mark on the left of the answer? Thanks